# Cómo puedo consultar o comparar valores dentro de un mismo array

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente array

```
$str = array('hellocat', 'a, t, hel, hello, b, cat');
```

Me gustaría establecer una función que tome la primera palabra (el primer item del array)
en el ejemplo es "hellocat", y busque en el segundo elemento, e identifique las dos palabras que componen la primera. Es como un diccionario.

```
function searchTwoWords($str){
    //Mi logica
    return $twoWord;
}
```

**Salida**

```
["hello", "cat"]
```

Otro ejemplo seria;

**Entrada**

```
$str = array("basketball", "ju, ba, basket, c, otro, ball")
```

**Salida**

```
['basket', 'ball']
```

Por favor, agradecería mucho su ayuda ya que no he encontrado la forma de hacerlo. Ni siquiera he podido imaginar la lógica que se precisa.
Espero haberme dado a entender. Gracias.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que dicha función tambien tendría que tener como parámetro  el límite en que se separarán las palabras `function name(array, size)`, ya que el compilador no sabe que 'basketball'  son `{'basket','ball'}`.

Comment: @denso gracias por comentar. La lógica según mi corta experiencia sería, encontrar sólo dos palabras del segúndo item que formen la palabra del primer ítem. No sé si sería con un método rand, o iterar, primero separar el segundo item en un array utilizando el delimitador "," e ir iterando.

Comment: Comienza por hacer un ciclo que recorra los elementos que podrían componer la palabra.

Comment: @denso Si asumimos que no se pueden repetir las palabras ya conocemos el número máximo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por cada elemento de tu array de palabras deberías concatenarlo con el resto de los elementos del mismo array. Puede ser de dos maneras. Primero uno adelante y el otro atrás y luego el otro adelante y el uno atrás.
Esta concatenación debes compararla contra tu palabra a buscar.
Si hay match retornas ambas palabras utilizadas en la concatenación y si no retornas un array vacío.

El código quedaría así:

```
$str = array('hellocat', 'a, t, hel, hello, b, cat');


function searchTwoWords($arr) {

    $needle = $arr[0];
    $haystack = $arr[1];

    $haystackElements = explode(',', $haystack);
    $haystackElements = array_map('trim', $haystackElements); // eliminar espacios en blanco de los elementoss del array
    $len = count($haystackElements);

    for($i=0; $i<$len-1; $i++) {  // Recorrer el array hasta el anteultimo elemento
        for($j=$i+1; $j<$len; $j++) {  // recorrer el array a partir del siguiente elemento y hasta el final

            if($needle == $haystackElements[$i] . $haystackElements[$j]){ // concatenar los elementos y ver si son lo que buscamos
                return array($haystackElements[$i], $haystackElements[$j]);
            }
            elseif ($needle == $haystackElements[$j] . $haystackElements[$i]) { // concatenar en el orden inverso
                return array($haystackElements[$j], $haystackElements[$i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return array();  // Si no hubo match retornar array vacio

}

print_r(searchTwoWords($str));
```

Comment: muchas gracias. El código funcionó. Tendré que revisarlo en detalle y durante bastante tiempo para poder comprenderlo. Me sorprende y me pregunto si algún día llegaré a ese nivel! Muchas gracias.